# Regular expression with brackets

Tags: php, regex, expression

How to get 'text' from this string:

```
{L[text]}
```

?

I tried

```
\{L\[*\]\}
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: If you would like to target almost any character classes use the dot inside your brackets like so: `\[.*\]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following expression?

```
/\{L\[([^\]]*)\]\}/
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, got blinded by all the characters. :)

Comment: Im getting this error:
preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: I think you might have to wrap the pattern with slashes, ie ``/pattern/``.

Comment: Ok, now I have Array ( [0] => {L[test]} [1] => test ), can I get only 'test' in array?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible without actually manipulating the array itself afterwards. First field is usually the matched String, where the following values are the "captured" ones.

Answer (score 3):

The allowed characters class is missing:

```
\{L\[(\w*)\]\}
```

Where \w = [a-zA-Z0-9].
Required text is in group 1.

[Demo](http://regexr.com?31g8e)

Comment: Don't forget the grouping though, as he wanted to get the content from inbetween the brackets!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$s = "{L[hello you]}";
preg_match('/\{L\[(.*)\]\}/', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I'm gettin:
Array ( [0] => {L[test]} [1] => test ) 

Can i get only 'test' ?